# Is there a way to pass multiple values to more than 1 separate arguments of a function in R?

Tags: r, function, loops

I have this function which takes in 3 arguments. First argument is a list of dataframes. The second argument is a dataframe. Third argument is a simple numerical value. I would like to change different parameters of the function to see what suits me best and record the results. But I have 15 things to go through for each of the arguments ie 15 lists, 15 dataframes. 
So is there a way to speed up the process.

I tried a do.call approach and sapply approach with no success. But I think I'm failing to properly create a list with the arguments i want.

```
matchloop <- function(data, data2, x) {
#first argument is used
split <- data
...
 #second argument is used
 while(nrow(tempdf0.3) >= 1 && m <= (nrow(data2))/2) {
  ...
  #second argument used again
  tempdf0.1 <- as.data.frame(data2[n:m,], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  ...
  #third argument is used
  tempdf0.3 <- mutate(tempdf0.3, routeID = (subset(tempdf0.5, 
  routeID != x)$routeID))
  ...
 }
 #return output
 return(tempdf0.3)
}
```

If it is one by one I can just go ahead and do matchloop(1st list, 1st df, 1st value) and then keep repeating for 2nd, 3rd....
So is there a way i can do all of them in one go?

Comment: maybe `mapply()` or `purrr::pmap()`

Comment: I would suggest using `combinations()` or `permutations()` to get the output you are looking for. For example if you wish to use the lists look at 5 lists at and any one of the data frames then use `combinations(n = 15, r = 5, v = 1:15)` and save it as a matrix. This will give you indices that you can pass into the function so you don't have to manually type each combination.